# Compiler omitting outer loop

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have implemented (read: copy&pasted from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXTEA#Reference_code)) the XXTEA cipher in a C++ project. For clarity reasons I separated the encryption and decryption in separate functions: (NOTE: this is not a cryptography question! Please do not comment on the chosen cipher)

```
#define DELTA 0x9e3779b9
#define MX (((z>>5^y<<2) + (y>>3^z<<4)) ^ ((sum^y) + (key[(p&3)^e] ^ z)))
static void btea_enc( unsigned int *v, unsigned n, const unsigned int* key ) {
    unsigned int y, z, sum;
    unsigned p, rounds, e;
    rounds = 16 + 52/n;
    sum = 0;
    z = v[n-1];
    do {
        sum += DELTA;
        e = (sum >> 2) & 3;
        for (p=0; p<n-1; p++) {
            y = v[p+1]; 
            z = v[p] += MX;
        }
        y = v[0];
        z = v[n-1] += MX;
    } while (--rounds);
}
static void btea_dec( unsigned int *v, unsigned n, const unsigned int* key ) {
    unsigned int y, z, sum;
    unsigned p, rounds, e;
    rounds = 16 + 52/n;
    sum = rounds*DELTA;
    y = v[0];
    do {
        e = (sum >> 2) & 3;
        for (p=n-1; p>0; p--) {
            z = v[p-1];
            y = v[p] -= MX;
        }
        z = v[n-1];
        y = v[0] -= MX;
    } while ((sum -= DELTA) != 0);
}
#undef MX
#undef DELTA
```

When this code is compiled in Debug, it works perfectly. However when I compile this code with (default) optimizations with Visual Studio 2013 (v120), btea_dec loses its outer loop (causing the decryption to produce garbage).

The disassembly listing for [encryption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qna70.png) and [decryption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW3Zw.png). Notice the missing outer loop during decryption! (if you'd like the code as text, I'd be happy to upload, it's just a wall of text)

Looking at the actual code, the end condition is an overflowing unsigned int 'sum':
`while ((sum -= DELTA) != 0)`
I don't understand what the compiler did to make it think it could get rid of this loop (afaik overflow is only undefined for integers, unsigned overflow is perfectly fine).

Question: Why is the compiler 'optimizing' the outer loop away? And how do I fix it?

MCVE: (paste the previous code block containing btea_enc and btea_dec between include & main)

```
#define _CRT_RAND_S
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Random key
    unsigned int key[4];
    rand_s(&key[0]);
    rand_s(&key[1]);
    rand_s(&key[2]);
    rand_s(&key[3]);

    // Buffer we'll be encrypting
    unsigned int utext[4];
    memcpy(utext, "SecretPlaintext", 16);

    // Encrypt
    btea_enc(utext, 4, key);

    // Decrypt
    btea_dec(utext, 4, key);

    // Should still be equal!
    bool s = !strcmp((char*)utext, "SecretPlaintext");

    // Print message
    printf("Compared: %s\n", s ? "equal" : "falsly");

    return s?0:1;
}
```

Comment: How large are your ints? With `n` equal to `1`, `(16 + 52/n) * 0x9e3779b9` gives `180501632292`, which is quite large.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Target both Win32 and Win64, Debug builds work fine. sizeof(unsigned int)==4 (dword).

Comment: @Mat Shouldn't be, `unsigned op signed` shall be evaluated in `unsigned`.

Comment: @Mat: DELTA is an unsigned int, since it is hexadecimal and doesn't fit into an int.

Comment: please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that someone else can try to reproduce the problem

Comment: @gnasher9729 unless int is 64bit (which it probably isn't in VS)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks, that was trivially easy to reproduce: [link](http://www.casualhacks.net/temp/MCVE_XXTEA.rar) - Open with Visual Studio 2013, compile Release & Debug - Run both, Debug will print "Compares: equal", Release will print "Compares: falsly"

Comment: The compiler may optimize away loops which contain Undefined Behavior at runtime, because it's a valid assumption they're run 0 times. So if MSVC++ can prove anything in the outer loop is UB, it can assume rounds==0.

Comment: @MSalters as shown by gnasher729's answer, it appears to be related to the (intentionally overflowing) `unsigned int sum`. Everything I've read suggests that only signed integers are UB when overlfowing, unsigned integers behave exactly as you'd expect them to. Thus the question becomes: where is the UB?

Comment: @MicroCode See my answer. `DELTA` is signed.

Comment: the problem is triggered by the use the "Whole Program Optimization" (`/GL`) option.  I don't know if that means there's a bug in `/GL` or if that option exposes UB in a different way here.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: With `/GL`, the compiler knows that `rounds == 29`, which might trigger more optimizations.

Comment: @MichaelBurr confirmed. Disabling whole program optimization makes the test case print 'Compared: equal' in all cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WIth /GL, the compiler knows that `n == 4` and therefore `rounds == 29`.  It's surely precomputing the initial value of `sum`, which is `rounds*DELTA`, as well.

Next, it may try to calculate the number of loop iterations and unroll the outer loop.  If it's doing that wrongly (as I did in my other answer), it may be doing `uint32_t(rounds * DELTA) / DELTA`, which is one.  Add the first iteration for being a do-while, and that's where the outer loop went.

gnasher's loop control code is much easier for a compiler to figure out, there are exactly `rounds` (29) iterations, which it might or might not decide to unroll, but there's very little room to mess up the number of iterations.

Comment: That sounds like a very reasonable explanation! Thanks. I still can't believe I found an actual compiler bug. I've blamed the compiler many times, but this is the first where I'm right :)

Answer (score 1):

*Why* this happens is beyond me. You could try replacing

```
} while ((sum -= DELTA) != 0);
```

with

```
    sum -= DELTA;
} while ((--rounds) != 0);
```

Comment: My first attempt of just moving the `sum -= DELTA` outside the while, and put `while(sum)` failed. Your change does work! Unless someone can explain why this happens I'll mark this as the solution.

Comment: @MicroCode what is `sizeof(int)` on your system, what is `n` when it fails, and can you confirm you are compiling as C++?

Comment: @MattMcNabb sizeof(int)==sizeof(unsigned int)==4, MCVE was added to (bottom of) OP, I'm pretty sure this is x86 C++ :)

Comment: @MicroCode Post the code in the question, not as an external link. If it's too big for the question then it wasn't really "Minimal".

Comment: @MattMcNabb The reason I linked externally was because I wanted to make sure it wasn't some project setting. Code is in the OP, I hope I didn't miss an include.

Comment: @MicroCode: please open a bug on Microsoft Connect - this sure feels like a bug with `/GL` codegen/optimization.

Comment: Note that this is different logic if `rounds * DELTA` and `UINT_MAX+1` are not relatively prime.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I have no idea how to do this but I'll try

Comment: Go to: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio and click on "open a bug". You'll need to have (or set up) a Microsoft account. If you prefer not to, let me know and I'll post the bug.

Comment: @MicroCode: Thanks for linking the bug report here.  I've also linked back to this question from there; experience is that MS engineers often read related discussion on SO, and sometimes even come back and post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:  That MACRO is very very bad programming style.  Rewrite it with arguments, like

```
#define MX(key,sum,p,e,y,z) (((z>>5^y<<2) + (y>>3^z<<4)) ^ ((sum^y) + (key[(p&3)^e] ^ z)))
```

so that someone reading your code can actually see what variables appear in the expression.

Better yet, use an inline function.

---

<strike>The compiler is correct to optimize away the nested loop, since the visible side-effects are predictable.</strike>

The only visible side effect is `v[p] -= MX;` and this occurs a predictable number of times.  So the compiler can replace the nested loops by `v[p] -= loopcount * MX;`

`e`, `z`, and `y` are written repeatedly but never read, so the compiler can eliminate them, and their calculations, entirely.

Note that such optimizations of impotent operations may expose you you timing attacks that you thought you carefully eliminated.

The whole function body becomes

```
int p=n;
int subtrahend = rounds * DELTA / DELTA * MX;
do {
   v[--p] -= subtrahend;
} while (p);
```

Comment: Except that the `MX` macro evaluates (or reads) `e`, `y` and `z` which are updated in the loop.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Macro!!?!!  People are still using those?  With implicit arguments?  That does change the analysis :(

Comment: Unfortunately, macros like this seem pretty common in crypto code.  At least in this one, the macro doesn't rely on implicit argument *and* produce side effects, which is a technique I've seen used more than once in crypto (or maybe compression) code.

Comment: The code comes from wikipedia (note: I edited the cleaned up version to use gnasher728's workaround), whose users already tried to clean it up. Since crypto is a tricky business I obviously didn't try to mess with it (too much).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: It wouldn't be as bad if the macro were defined inside the function, where the variables it uses are in scope.  The fact that it is taking advantage of dynamic capture of identifiers that aren't even in scope yet... is a recipe guaranteed to induce misunderstanding on the first and second readthrough.